# Display a button after promises are resolved

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function inside which i have 3 api calls with promises. How can I display a button when all promises are resolved.

I had to make different function  which i execute after first function. But that only increases buttons and functions in my code.

Need a code to wait until all requests execute and variables get some data and then display a button.

```
 function somefunction(){
    zoho.crm.connection.invoke(shtCon,req_data).then(fucntion(response){
    status1 = response.status;
    })
    zoho.crm.connection.invoke(shtCon,req_data).then(fucntion(response){
    status2 = response.status;
    })
    zoho.crm.connection.invoke(shtCon,req_data).then(fucntion(response){
        status3 = response.status;
     })
    }
```

Comment: Please include any relevant code in your question. Questions with code are much more likely to be answered by the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve your goal is to see if all calls are resolved after each api response.

Some solution like this will work.

```
let status1, status2, status3;
function somefunction( ){
    status1 = null, status2 = null, status3 = null;
    zoho.crm.connection.invoke(shtCon,req_data).then(fucntion(response){
        status1 = response.status;
        checkIfAllCallsAreDone();
    })
    zoho.crm.connection.invoke(shtCon,req_data).then(fucntion(response){
        status2 = response.status;
        checkIfAllCallsAreDone();
    })
    zoho.crm.connection.invoke(shtCon,req_data).then(fucntion(response){
        status3 = response.status;
        checkIfAllCallsAreDone();
    })
}

function checkIfAllCallsAreDone() {
    if(status1 && status2 && status3) {
        // Do your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: this function executes on a button click. At the first click it executes only once which is correct but the second time it executes 3 times and so on. Please suggest.

Comment: @VipinYadav Reset the status variables before making second call. I have updated that in the answer.